# How to delete files older than x seconds (not days, hours or minutes) on shell?

Tags: bash, awk

There are many questions on how to delete files older than x minutes/hours/days on linux, but no one get to the seconds resolution.

I've found this solution:

```
for file in `ls -ltr --time-style=+%s | awk '{now=systime(); del_time=now-30; if($6<del_time && $5=="0") print $7}'` ;do
   rm -f $file >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

But `systime()` is not present on `awk`

> "function systime never defined"

but is on `gawk` which I couldn't install on Ubuntu 13.xx (and really don't whant to install any extra software).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Parsing output of `ls` is always a bad approach. Especially when `find` from GNU Findutils is able to do all the work by itself:

```
$ find -not -newermt '-30 seconds' -delete
```

Comment: This is excelent! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A solution I found is to replace `systime()` command, and use `date +%s` like this:

```
for file in $(ls -ltr --time-style=+%s | awk '{cmd="date +%s"; cmd|getline now; close(cmd);del_time=now-30; if($6<del_time) print $7}') ;do
   rm -f $file >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

The trick is to capture the output of `date +%s` inside `awk` and using `cmd="date +%s"; cmd|getline now; close(cmd)` was the only (really the first) way that I've found.

Edit: I changed backticks to parentheses, as recomended by @Jotne

Comment: You should not use old and outdated backtics, use parentheses like this: `for file in $(ls -ltr --time-style=+%s | awk '{cmd="date +%s"; cmd|getline now; close(cmd);del_time=now-30; if($6<del_time) print $7}') ;do`

Comment: NEVER parse output from ls... filenames can contain weird characters (like `\n`...

Comment: You can parse ls -ltr if you want as each filename is on a different line. Also you can use backticks if you want as the functionality is the same.

Comment: Backticks are obsolete and are *not* the same, which is the reason why backticks are against best practices. The most important difference is that parentheses can be nested whereas backticks cannot.